# py2exe and QSplashScreen

Tags: python, pyqt4, py2exe

I want to add QSplashScreen to PyQT4 application. It works fine from Python,
but when I create exe with py2exe, a splash image is invisible, the app waits 2 sec and shows the main window. What is wrong?

Application code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Create and display the splash screen
    splash_pix = QPixmap('images/splash.jpg')
    splash = QSplashScreen(splash_pix, QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    splash.setMask(splash_pix.mask())
    splash.show()
    app.processEvents()

    time.sleep(2)

    myapp = Main()
    myapp.show()
    splash.finish(myapp)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from py2exe.build_exe import py2exe
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='-',
      version='1.0',
      description='-',
      author='-',
      author_email='-',
      windows=[{"script": "main.py"}],
      data_files=[
                ('phonon_backend', [
                    'C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\phonon_backend\phonon_ds94.dll'
                    ]),
                  'settings.yaml',
                  ('images', ['images/accept.png',
                              'images/splash.jpg',

                              ]),
                  'loader.png',
                  'licence.txt',
                  'about.txt',
                  ],
     )
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior? Does the exe generate a log file when it runs with errors and stack traces, or is it failing silently? Do you have any sort of logging implemented that might let you see what location it's trying to access the splash image from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PNG support comes by default, JPEG support is by a plugin which will need to be included in some way.

There was a thread recently on the PySide mailing list about this sort of thing with cx_freeze, starts at http://lists.pyside.org/pipermail/pyside/2010-December/001656.html. the solution will be approximately the same for PyQt4 and py2exe.

The [final solution](http://lists.pyside.org/pipermail/pyside/2010-December/001662.html) there was basically this:

Next to the produced .exe file, put `qt.conf` with this in it:

```
[Paths]
Plugins = plugins
```

(You could use a value other than "plugins", change the subdirectory name to match.)

Create a subdirectory `plugins` and in it another subdirectory `imageformats`. Copy `qjpeg4.dll` in here. It'll be in a path like `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats`.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you need QT's qjpeg4.dll. Try copying the following folder:

```
<python-dir>\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats
```

into the folder containing the exe that py2exe creates.

That's where it'll be if you installed from the PyQt4 binary setup file from the Riverbank site. If you have a different install setup, hunt around.